# Como abrir um arquivo .php que está em um subdiretorio?

Tags: php, html5

Meu index.php tem esse script dentro dele:

```
<?php

$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

switch ($pagina):
case 'contato':
    $titulo = 'Contato ';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

case 'privacidade':
    $titulo = 'Privacidade ';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

case 'ultimasnoticias':
    $titulo = 'Ultimas Noticias';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

default:
    $titulo = 'Home';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    $pagina = 'home';
endswitch;
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
</head>
<body>

    <?php require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php'; ?>

<footer>Rodapé</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu estou tenho muita dificuldade em explicar o meu problema, então eu tentei explicar usando a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: nao sei se entendi, mas colocando require_once 'posts/page_' ....... nao é isso?

Comment: se é o que quer saber, para acessar arquivos dentro de diretórios, usa-se `/`, por exemplo, `posts/meuprimeiropost.php`

Comment: Tenho que dizer: você conseguiu resumir o problema nessa imagem muito melhor que nas outras 4 ou 5 vezes juntas. Agora sim será possível elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: Ufa, pelo menos agora veio um post que de fato tem alguma coisa que abre arquivo! Os outros anteriores nao falavam nada do require. Veja se na próxima já faz a pergunta com todos os detalhes em vez de criar 3289 contas (e achar que é perseguição). Com detalhes fica possível de te ajudarem. Sem detalhes, não há boa vontade que permita adivinhar o que vc quer.

Comment: @Bacco Me desculpe, eu sou novato em PHP, então eu não sabia quais códigos eram relevantes em mostrar, mas eu percebi que na duvida é melhor mostrar tudo relacionado (sem exagero).

Comment: Sim, e pare de achar que estamos perseguindo. Simplesmente leia o que é pedido nos comentários e tente ajudar a gente a resolver seu problema. Ficar criando contas e contas e repostando a mesma coisa atrapalha o site todo. Basta editar a pergunta conforme os comentários pedem sua ajuda, e criar pergunta nova só depois de resolver o passo anterior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve dar um jeito de passar o nome do post para o seu script php. Poderia até usar o mesmo atributo `p` e dar uma alterada no código atual, ou ainda usar outro atributo e passar o nome do post. Mostrarei usando a 2ª opção.

Primeiro, defina a nova variável, vou usar aqui no exemplo a variável `post` via `GET`. Também defini as outras variáveis aqui no começo do script

```
$titulo = '';
$keywords = '';
$descricao = '';
$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];
```

No caso, o código da decisão sobre a página que já existe só deve rodar caso a variável não seja informada, ou venha em branco. Nesse caso, pode colocar todo o `switch` dentro de um `if`. Coloque um `else` se quiser preencher as outras variáveis.

```
if (empty($post)) {
    // switch aqui
} else {
    $titulo = 'Post';
}
```

E finalmente, na hora do `require_once`, veja novamente se o `$post` está vazio, se estiver faça o que já faz hoje, senão chame o arquivo em `/post`.

```
if (empty($post)) {
    require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php';
} else {
    require_once 'posts/' . $post . '.php';
}
```

Para criar o link dentro das páginas, digamos para o post `meuArquivo.php` como você colocou na imagem, seria assim:

```
<a href="index.php?post=meuArquivo">Meu Arquivo</a>
```

Agora, o script com tudo junto ficaria assim:

```
<?php

$titulo = '';
$keywords = '';
$descricao = '';
$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];

$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

if (empty($post)) {
    switch ($pagina):
    case 'contato':
        $titulo = 'Contato ';
        break;
    case 'privacidade':
        $titulo = 'Privacidade ';
        break;
    case 'ultimasnoticias':
        $titulo = 'Ultimas Noticias';
        break;

    default:
        $titulo = 'Home';
        $pagina = 'home';
    endswitch;
} else {
    $titulo = 'Post';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (empty($post)) {
    require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php';
} else {
    require_once 'posts/' . $post . '.php';
}
?>

<footer>Rodapé</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Funcionou perfeitamente, só tem uma coisa que você explicou e eu acho que eu não entendi direito, sendo assim, nos arquivos do meu diretório principal esta mostrando essa mensagem de erro logo acima do header `Notice: Undefined index: post in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php on line 6` essa é a linha 6 `$post = $_GET['post'];`.

Comment: Tente trocar por `$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];` e veja se a mensagem some. Se sumir eu atualizo a resposta

Comment: A mensagem sumiu, tá perfeito. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mesmo! Obs: Está faltando um ")" nessas linhas `if (empty($post)`

Comment: Eu notei que não estou conseguindo alterar o valor do `$titulo` `$descricao` e `$keywords` dos arquivos que estão dentro da pasta "posts". Eu deveria informar os valores dessas variáveis no `case` certo? Eu só consigo alterar os valores nas variáveis que estão no topo depois do <?php, mas eu preciso colocar um `$titulo`...etc, unico para cada página que está dentro da pasta "posts".

Comment: Arrumei ali... Sobre os valores, não vou ter como testar aqui, mas você tentou imprimir eles depois do `require_once`? Tenho quase certeza que eles mudam, por serem globais. O problema é que você imprime eles antes de mudar né? O mesmo deve ocorrer na `descricao` e `keywords` com as outras páginas, se você reparar.

Uma saída é você declarar algumas funções em todas essas páginas, como `getTitulo()` e `getConteudo()`, fazer o `require_once` antes de escrever a página e substituir essas variáveis por essas funções... vale um teste

Comment: Acredito que isso pode ser uma nova pergunta, talvez seja melhor criar uma nova...

Comment: Tudo bem colega, obrigado, sua ajuda teve um papel fundamental no meu projeto.

Answer (score 2):

Para acessar arquivos de outra pasta não tem segredo:

Você está em:
**index.php**

```
<a href="posts/meuArquivo.php">Página 1 </a>
```

Agora você está em:
**posts/meuArquivo.php** e quer voltar para **index** ou outro arquivo irmão de index:

```
<a href="/">Página 1 </a>

<a href="/page_home.php">Página 1 </a>
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Exatamente, como faço isso? Eu tentei colocar um require embaixo do outro require que está no index.php mas não deu certo. Eu suponho que eu preciso de somente 1 require no index,php juntamente com uma variavel que esteja configurada para fazer o que eu expliquei na imagem.

Comment: Pode fazer um if  antes e chamar assim o require com a variavel correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem mais vamos lá.

1. Para abri o link do diretório [posts] você utiliza

   ```
   < a href="/post/nome_arquivo.php"> arquivo da pasta post < /a >
   ```

Caso você não queira apontar o diretório, pode passar um parâmetro via $`_GET` e no seu *switch* você trata qual pagina dar um `required_once`.
meu conselho é que você não faça isso **'page_' . $pagina . '.php'** 
E no seu case coloque algo do tipo case `'ultimasnoticias': $pagina = "caminho/ultimasnoticias.php"`.
Informando o caminho completo para ser direcionado.

2. credito que respondi no primeiro item.

   < a href="/post/nome_arquivo.php"> arquivo da pasta post < /a >